# How to pass env var to Docusaurus v2

Tags: command-line, documentation, docusaurus

I've been trying to get environment variables to work in my documentation build.
I've had some success with adding a `dotenv-webpack` plugin and substituting values that way.
This has the downside of needing a `.env` file of some kind

I would like to have my build know of environment variables automatically ie. everything that is output from `printenv`

I've tried adding this to package.json:
`TEST_ENV_VAR=working docusaurus start"`
But when I log the `process.env` object there is nothing there.

How can I make this work?

Comment: Was there ever an answer for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I created a plugin that adds the functionality of `dotenv-webpack` to Docusaurus2's webpack config.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusaurus2-dotenv

You should be able to `npm install docusaurus2-dotenv`, enable `systemvar`, and add it to your plugin section and your `systemvar` values will be accessible e.g. `process.env.PATH`.

This would allow you to make use of `.env` files (if you decide want to use them in the future), as well as any environment variables that get created during CI or that exist on the machine that is building the code.

```js
docusaurus.config.js

module.exports = {
  ..., // other docusaurus2 config
  plugins: [
    [
      "docusaurus2-dotenv",
      {
        systemvars: true,
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks very much!

Comment: I've been stuck on how to use env variables in Docusaurus for days! You made my day buddy! 

Answer (score 9):

### Build time environment variables

There are **two steps:**

- Run `npm i --save-dev dotenv`
- In your `docusaurus.config.js`, just add:

```js
require('dotenv').config()
```

- Confirm your `.env` directory contains environment variables, e.g.

```sh
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_1=hello_there
```

Your `.env` file will be loaded, and you can use `process.env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_1` now.

### Runtime environment variables:

To use `process.env` variables in React components for example, do the builtime environment variables steps above, then use the `customFields` field of the docusaurus config object:

```js
const config = {
  ...
  customFields: {
    'ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_1': process.env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_1,
    'ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_2': process.env.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_2,
  },
  ...
}
```

and in my typescript component, access them with:

```
const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();

  return <div>{`${siteConfig.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_1}`}</div>;
```

Read [Custom Configurations](https://docusaurus.io/docs/configuration#custom-configurations) in the docusaurus documentation for more information.

### Comment

[Jonny Nabors's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61687536/7365866) (and package) was unnecessary for me and actually confused me. If you want your build process to use your environment variables, use the extremely popular npm package that has been downloaded 22 million times this week ([dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv), rather than his package ([docusaurus2-dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusaurus2-dotenv)), which did not work for me.

Perhaps his package is more useful if you needed to use the environment variables at runtime whilst avoiding adding it to the configuration object like I did above? However, in that case, I also found another solution, which is to use environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`.

Comment: With Docusaurus 3, you need to access the custom fields with the `customFields` object. @ben-butterworth 's example would be:
`const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();`
`return <div>{\`${siteConfig.customFields.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_1}\`}</div>;`

Answer (score 4):

The question I have is **Why can't we use process.env.VARIABLE?**

Reading how [Docusaurus.useDocusaurusContext works](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/blob/v2.0.0-beta.20/packages/docusaurus/src/client/docusaurusContext.tsx#L11), a developer can read the config variables using `import siteConfig from '@generated/docusaurus.config';`. So the solution looks like:

**docusaurus.config.js**

```
const config = {
  customFields: {
    // application environment (i.e. staging or prod)
    env: process.env.REACT_APP_ENV,
  },
  ...
}
```

**myUtil.ts**

```
import siteConfig from '@generated/docusaurus.config';

if (siteConfig.customFields.env === 'prod') {
 // do something for prod
}
```

Then, restart the server using

```
export REACT_APP_ENV="prod"
yarn start
```

Importing `docusaurus.config.js` directly into the application results in the error `process is not defined`. This requires a webpack configuration, which I didn't want to get into.

*Note*: This method is not documented so use with care.

Comment: This was a useful addition for me.

Comment: FYI siteConfig.customFields.ENV should be siteConfig.customFields.env

Answer (score 1):

Just as a future reference, there is now an official section in the docusaurus documentation addressing this issue: https://docusaurus.io/docs/deployment#using-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

We ran into this problem while developing [jsPlumb Components](https://components.jsplumbtoolkit.com/), and we wrote a Docusaurus plugin to assist:

https://github.com/jsplumb/docusaurus-plugin-env-loader-json

With this plugin you manage your environment specific values in a JSON file:

```
{
    "production":{
        "SERVER_URL":"https://some.server.com/anEndpoint"
    },
    "development":{
        "SERVER_URL":"http://localhost:4200/anEndpoint"
    }
}
```

which you then access via the `customFields` of your site config:

```
import useDocusaurusContext from '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext';

export function MyApp {

    const {siteConfig} = useDocusaurusContext();
    const serverUrl = siteConfig.customFields.SERVER_URL

    ...

}
```

The selection of `production` vs `development` is made by inspecting the `NODE_ENV` environment variable.

The plugin is on npm:

```
npm i --save-dev @jsplumb/docusaurus-plugin-env-loader-json
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use `docusaurus2-dotenv` you will get his issue**

```
[ERROR] TypeError: dep.getModuleEvaluationSideEffectsState is not a function?
```

Instead install [`docusaurus-plugin-dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docusaurus-plugin-dotenv) and add it like this to your plugins config in `daucusaurus.config.js`

```json
plugins: 
[
...
    [
      'docusaurus-plugin-dotenv',
      {
          path: "./.env", 
          systemvars: true, 
      }
    ]
....
]
```

Now in your app you can use env variable normally ex:

```
import React from "react";
import { Auth0Provider } from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import Login from "../auth/Login";

const DOMAIN = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN;
const CLIENTID = process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_CLIENTID;
....
```